# AngularJS: access scope from bootstrap-ui accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to $watch for a change on a model within a ui-bootstrap accordion. Binding works within the view, but when the model changes, the $watch doesn't fire.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DcoGT2?p=preview

How do I get the value of $scope.myModel in the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an object rather than a primitive:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      <input ng-model="model.myModel"> {{ model.myModel }}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.model = {myModel: ''};
  $scope.$watch('model.myModel',function(){
    console.log($scope.model.myModel);
  })
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7P461q?p=preview)

Comment: This just fixed an issue for me - but can someone point me to an explanation of why a primitive doesn't work here?

Comment: @henry, probably because the accordion-group directive creates a child scope, so the child gets a copy, not a reference.  For more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs